# Button and ImageButton not elevated-not animated by default with AppCompat v7 on Lollipop device

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-appcompat

Using AppCompat v7, inheriting theme from AppCompat theme, running my app on Lollipop device or Emulator, `Buttons` and `ImageButtons` respond with ripple effect on touch but are neither elevated nor animated on the click. Should not be default features?

**Manifest.xml**:

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

**Update**
It seems that:

- `ImageButton` has only ripple effect by default
- `Button` works with default features but misses ripple effect, elevation and z-animation on click if is present personalized `android:background` property (as color or selector) in xml element

Comment: In my opinion it is not the same: I am experiencing the default behavior of appcompat v7 on platform lollipop for buttons, depending on the presence or absence of `android:background` property.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure elevation is not supported in the support lib.

Comment: I am testing my app with AppCompat v7 running on Lollipop platform device.